# Set starting position of collectionView

Tags: ios, swift3

If I set starting position 21 and end index is 35, the collectionView will display buttons from 21 to 35, not from 0 to 35.
Is there any way we can achieve this in collectionView?

I am fetching value from firebase and that values are rollNoFrom and rollNoTo

**Code:**

```
 var mainArrayRoll = [String]()
 var rangeArray = [String]()
 var rollFrom = Int()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.takeAttandanceCollection.delegate=self
    self.takeAttandanceCollection.dataSource=self
    let ref =   Database.database().reference().child("Subject").child("DBMS")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            self.temp = (userDict["RollNoTo"]! as! String)
            self.temp2 = (userDict["RollNoFrom"]! as! String)
            self.rollTo=Int(self.temp)!
            self.rollFrom=Int(self.temp)!
            print(self.rollTo)
            self.mainArrayRoll=self.rangeArray[self.rollFrom...self.rollTo]
            self.takeAttandanceCollection?.reloadData()

            }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make one `range` array from your main array and use that range array with your `collectionView`. Now every time when starting position and ending position changed replace the range array with new range array and reload the `collectionView`.

```
var mainArray = [String]()
var rangeArray = [String]()
```

Now initialized the `rangeArray` from `mainArray` when start or end index is changed.

```
rangeArray = Array(mainArray[start...end])
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you @Nirav D After applying your solution it is giving me error:      Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'

Comment: @PratikSanap Edit your question with your tried code, so it will gave us idea what you are trying

Comment: I have  provided the code I am trying with your solution

Comment: @PratikSanap Changed line `self.mainArrayRoll=self.rangeArray[self.rollFrom...self.rollTo]` to `self.rangeArray=Array(self.mainArrayRoll[self.rollFrom...self.rollTo])`, I have edited answer also

Comment: it worked for me Thank you so much brother @Nirav D. Again Thanx

Comment: @PratikSanap Welcome mate :)